# Accounts getting stuck in System Validation

Tags: oim

In our OIM environment we are using rule based role membership & access policies to provision access to users.  My problem is that the accounts are being assigned to users but are being stopped at the 'System Validation' step.

To bypass this, the process definition should have the Auto Save Form checkbox checked.  It is.

If you manually assign roles to users, they don't get stopped at System Validation.

Are there other reasons that would force an account to stop at 'System Validation' instead of proceeding to the create step?

Comment: Some troubleshooting steps i've taken are to uncheck and recheck the checkbox on the process definition, create new process forms and new UI forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Validation is an OOTB task added in every process definition to check values for required fields.

If you want to make field optional then remove "Required=True" property for that specific attribute from designconsole.
Else, check process form fields which are marked as "Required=True" in designconsole.

All these fields must be populated before submitting for provisioning. System validation task just checks that these fields are not empty on the request form.

Comment: This is the cause.  I believe there is a timing issue related to the required fields causing system validation to not complete.